# GitLab CI encountered an error: command not found: ajv

Tags: linux, bash, docker, gitlab-ci, npx

- I got an error in GitLab CI.
- Before that, I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881610/how-do-i-fix-bash-in-gitlab-ci-bad-substitution/59882539?noredirect=1#comment105895542_59882539).
- The problem was solved, but there was a new problem.

`schema-test.sh` file contents:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Test all file ends with schema.json via ajv

CURRENT_DIR=`dirname "$0"`

cd $CURRENT_DIR

for SCHEMA_FILE in *.schema.json
do
    SAMPLE_FILE=samples/${SCHEMA_FILE/schema/sample}
    echo Schema file: $SCHEMA_FILE
    if [ -f $SAMPLE_FILE ]
    then
        echo Found sample file: $SAMPLE_FILE
        npx ajv -s $SCHEMA_FILE -d $SAMPLE_FILE
    else
        echo "*NO* sample file found for $SCHEMA_FILE"
    fi
done
```

Gitlab CI error message:

```
23 $ yarn test:schema
24 yarn run v1.21.1
25 $ ./src/schemas/schema-test.sh
26 Schema file: dev-assistant.schema.json
27 Found sample file: samples/dev-assistant.sample.json
28 npx: installed 6 in 1.124s
29 command not found: ajv
30 Schema file: form.schema.json
31 *NO* sample file found for form.schema.json
32 Schema file: news.schema.json
33 *NO* sample file found for news.schema.json
34 Schema file: repos.schema.json
35 Found sample file: samples/repos.sample.json
36 npx: installed 6 in 0.911s
37 command not found: ajv
38 Schema file: team-members.schema.json
39 Found sample file: samples/team-members.sample.json
40 npx: installed 6 in 0.902s
41 command not found: ajv
42 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
43 error Command failed with exit code 1.
47 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [`ajv` (Another JSON Schema Validator)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) is installed, make sure it does not to open an editor to ask you anything: according to [`zkat/npx` issue 116](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/116), instead of hanging, npx would say `command not found: xxx`.

Make sure `ajv` is properly configured first ([check its version](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/releases)):

> Ajv version 6.0.0 that supports draft-07 is released. It may require either migrating your schemas or updating your code (to continue using draft-04 and v5 schemas, draft-06 schemas will be supported without changes).
>
> Please note: To use Ajv with draft-06 schemas you need to explicitly add the meta-schema to the validator instance

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the connection between your answer and my question. Could you clarify it a bit? Thank you.

Comment: @liby The error message you see `command not found: ...` is sometimes triggered when the `npx xxx` command want to open an editor and might froze as a result. Instead of being frozen, it prints that error message.